# Vandermonde-type convolution with geometric term

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Is there a closed-form solution to the following sum?
\begin{align*}
f(r, s, n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}c^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}
\end{align*}
I know this corresponds to find the coefficient of $x^n$ of the generating function
\begin{align*}
(1+cx)^r(1+x)^s
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to proceed from here. Any inputs would be great!

Comment: Mathematica gives it as ${s\choose n}F(-n,-r,1-n+s,c)$ where $F$ is the 2F1 hypergeometric function.

Comment: I don't see much hope for anything simpler than what you wrote. If you want to know something more specific, e.g. asymptotics, it'll be possible to say more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible expression not very elegant. 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}c^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k} 
=  \sum_{j=n-s}^{r} \binom{r}{j} (1-c)^{r-j}c^j \binom{j+s}{n}.
$$
The proof begins with your idea: 
\begin{align*}
(1+cx)^r(1+x)^s 
&= ((1-c)+c(1+x))^r(1+x)^s \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^r\binom{r}{j} (1-c)^{r-j}c^j(1+x)^{j+s} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^r\binom{r}{j} (1-c)^{r-j}c^j \sum_{i=0}^{j+s}\binom{j+s}{i} x^i \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{s} x^n \sum_{j=0}^{r} \binom{r}{j} (1-c)^{r-j}c^j \binom{j+s}{n}\\
&\quad+\sum_{n=1}^{r} x^{n+s} \sum_{j=n}^{r} \binom{r}{j} (1-c)^{r-j}c^j \binom{j+s}{n+s}.
\end{align*}