# A binomial sum identity

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let
\begin{align*}
f(n, r, \pi, k) &= \sum_{z=0}^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{z}{s}\binom{n}{z}\binom{n-z}{r-s}(-1)^{r+s}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^{r/2-s}\pi^{z}(1-\pi)^{n-z}z^k
\end{align*}
I am postulating that $f$ is identically 0, based off some theoretical results from statistics. How would one go about in proving this? Are the above special cases of a class combinatorial identities?

Bonus: Another problem that came up in my research is
\begin{align*}
h(n, \pi) = \sum_{z=0}^{n}\frac{A(n, \pi, z)B(n, \pi, z)}{C(n, \pi, z)}\pi^{z}(1-\pi)^{n-z}\binom{n}{z}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
A(n, \pi, z) &= \sum_{r=2}^{n}\rho_r \sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{z}{s}\binom{n-z}{r-s}(-1)^{r+s}\left(\frac{r}{2}-s\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^{r/2-s+1} \\
B(n, \pi, z) &= \sum_{r=3}^{n}c_r \sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{z}{s}\binom{n-z}{r-s}(-1)^{r+s}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^{r/2-s} \\
C(n, \pi, z) &= 1+\sum_{r=2}^{n}\rho_r \sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{z}{s}\binom{n-z}{r-s}(-1)^{r+s}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^{r/2-s}
\end{align*}
where $\rho_r, c_r$ are constants. Notice that in this expression, the $r$ is being marginalized out. This I have no idea what it equates to, and I'm frankly a bit pessimistic is finding a closed-form for this. But any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the sum on $s$ can probably be simplified, search in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients the formulas for sum of products of binomial coefs

Comment: I did ask exactly that; in my previous post (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793225/vandermonde-type-convolution-with-geometric-term), the best someone could do is an expression involving hypergeometric functions

Comment: so try the sum on $z$ :) or try changing the triple product of binomial coefs to get a different sum on $s$. if it doesn't reduce to any formula on this forum, little chance that it can be simplified

Comment: That's what I've been struggling with. It's interesting, though, because most likely a sum on $z$ will involve another hypergeometric function, yet the sum on both $s, z$ will result in 0 (most likely, I confirmed this with several cases numerically).

Comment: since you seem to know the contour integral / generating function method (as in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1789628/276986 ) , can you write the whole double sum in term of contour integral of $(1+x/a)^z (1+x)^{n-z}$ etc., to see what it looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Something seems to be not correct, since the function can be written as
\begin{align*}
f(n, r, \pi, k) &= \sum_{z=0}^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{z}{s}\binom{n}{z}\binom{n-z}{r-s}(-1)^{r+s}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^{r/2-s}\pi^{z}(1-\pi)^{n-z}z^k\\
&=(-1)^r\pi^{\frac{r}{2}}(1-\pi)^{ n-\frac{r}{2}}
\sum_{z=0}^n\binom{n}{z}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^zz^k
\sum_{s=0}^r\binom{z}{s}\binom{n-z}{r-s}(-1)^s\left(\frac{1-\pi}{\pi}\right)^s
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
f(n=1,r=0,\pi,k)&=(1-\pi)\sum_{z=0}^1\binom{1}{z}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^zz^k\\
&=(1-\pi)\left(0+\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)\\
&=\pi
\end{align*}
contrary to your assumption $f\equiv 0$.